# Delay between messages (before rewrite)

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I was wondering, would it be possible to add a delay between a certain command, without using the @bot.command thing?

this has been a problem, due to me recently adding a currency command, that users can spam it. So I am wanting a 4-8 min delay between the command for each user, but I haven't been able to find it here.

Here's my code:

```
  if message.content.startswith('=work'):
    f=open("bal_" + user.name + ".txt", 'r+')

    bal = f.read()
    balance = f.read()

    print(str(bal))
    workvalue = (randint(12, 100))
    s = bal
    i = int(s)
    total = i+workvalue

    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()

    f.write(str(total))

    print('earned: ' + str(workvalue))
    print('Balance: ' + str(balance))
    print('Total: ' + str(total))

    embed = discord.Embed(title="You worked for: $" + str(workvalue), description='', color=0xdb7991)

    await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
    f.close()
```

Honestly, some of it is from other commands I have worked on (file creation, teams, etc.) but I haven't been able to add a delay *yet*

Comment: You can use a decorator to add cooldown to a command using `@bot.command`, but why do you want not to use this?

Comment: I've worked without the @bot.command too much and ive grown used to the other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but if 8 minutes have passed since they did the command, it will allow them to do it again.

```
work_timer = {}

if message.content.startswith('=work'):
    try:
        work_time = work_timer[message.author.id]
        work_timer[message.author.id] = time.time()
        if work_timer[message.author.id] - work_time <= 480:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "You're only allowed to work every 8 minutes")
            return
        else:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "{} works".format(message.author.mention))
    except KeyError:
        work_timer[message.author.id] = time.time()
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "{} works".format(message.author.mention))
```

Comment: work_time = work_timer[message.author.id]
KeyError: '251183486348689408'

That is a error i'm getting when trying to add in the code, including the storage system.

Comment: If you really added this code, you shouldn't get the KeyError this way as it is specifically catched in the `except` part.

Comment: Please edit your original question with the edited code so we can see what you have. You shouldn't be getting a KeyError because we catch it with an `except KeyError`